# Authenticate Windows/Linux process against hardware security module

Tags: authentication, memory, key, hsm

I have a hardware security module connected to a host computer (Windows/Linux). The HSM contains symmetric keys used to encrypt/decrypt data (i.e. files and real-time communications); the keys are stored inside the memory of the HSM and their values are never exposed outside of the HSM.

The HSM exposes a login/logout API towards the host computer, the user enters a PIN to login to the HSM in order to use its features (i.e. encrypt data). The login is performed inside the application that uses the HSM (i.e. a secure messaging program).

My question is: **how can I be sure that the requests sent to the HSM (i.e. decrypt data) have actually been sent by the program that performed the login against the HSM?** Because there could be some malicious software on the host computer that simply waits for the HSM to be connected and for the login to be performed by some application, at that point the malicious software could do all sorts of things with the HSM.

My **first idea** was to authenticate the requests of the process that performed the login using the same PIN used for the login, attaching some nonce to avoid replay attacks. However, this is a problem because the PIN needs to be stored as plaintext in RAM memory.

My **second idea** is the same as the first one, with the exception that during the login operation the process exchanges a secret with the HSM, that secret is then stored in RAM and used to authenticate the requests of that process. It could also be implemented a mechanism so that the secret expires every N seconds (or N requests to the HSM), this way I can periodically generate a new secret making very hard for an attacker to scan the memory, find the secret and use it before it has expired.

Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: Well, the user application shouldn't access the HSM directly. Requests should be realyed by the server application functioning as type of proxy. The request should be authenticated on the server (and for this you have a whole bunch of technics).

Comment: Also it is very much a case of vendor dependency.  The vendor supplies providers that act as the proxy between your application and the HSM.  If you want to know if that connection is secured (assuming the HSM is a network appliance version) just watch the traffic in wireshark.  And there will always be questions about how to secure the login keys.  If those are compromised, no HSM in the world can help you.